# Subtracting a value from all elements of a 2D list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a 2D list and I want to subtract a floating point value from all the elements of the 2D list:

```
mat = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
cons = 13
mat1 = cons - mat
```

But the last line doesn't work. How to do this in a 2D list in python?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know if you're using `numpy`? Are you expecting the syntax you've used for `mat` to work in Python?

Answer (score 5):

If you do a lot of such things, consider using `numpy`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: mat = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [3]: cons = 13

In [4]: cons-mat
Out[4]: 
array([[12, 11],
       [10,  9]])
```

Comment: +1: but depending on what is the project it could be a bit overkilling

Comment: @6502 Sure, that's why I added that little note before the code. But even in that case it might be worth it to look at `numpy` and get an idea of what it can do.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a nested list comprehension:

```
mat1 = [[(cons - x) for x in row] for row in mat]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot substract a number from a list or the other way round.
If you want to stick to the builtin list-type you could do this with a nested comprehension:

```
mat1 = [[cons - m for m in sublist] for sublist in mat]
```

If your lists are, presumably, larger than the one in your example it might be worthwhile to check out the numpy module, which allows such operations.