# How can I automate arithmetic for a list structure in Python?

Tags: python, math, for-loop

Input:

```
['mia', 5, 10]
['mia', 20, 50]
['mia', 52, 101]
['mia', 220, 380]
```

My code (which works but I'd like to get it automated without typing `print` by hand all the time):

```
print lines[1][1] - lines[0][2]
print lines[2][1] - lines[1][2]
```

Output:

```
10
2
119
```

To automate this printing process I tried using a `for` loop:

```
for x in lines:
    print lines[x][1] - lines[x-1][2]
```

And received the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`

Then I tried:

```
for int(x) in lines:
    print lines[int(x)][1] - lines[int(x)-1][2]
```

And received the error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

I examined [Subtracting a value from all elements of a 2D list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591813/subtracting-a-value-from-all-elements-of-a-2d-list-in-python) but it did not help me to figure out my problem.

Any help is appreciated to get my arithmetic process automated (either using a `for` loop so I can understand how I could improve my code above, or some other structure).  Bonus points for showing how to define a function or create a class definition to accomplish this task.

Comment: `for x in lines:` can you figure out why you get the TypeError? You can `print x` and it should become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case `x in lines` means `x` takes the value of each line. I.e., first `x = ['mia', 5, 10]`, then `x = ['mia', 20, 50]`... This isn't what you want. You want `x = 0`, `x = 1`...

But by trying to simply making `x` into an integer by writing `int(x)` what you are saying is on the first iteration of the loop assign `['mia', 5, 10]` to `int(x)`, and so on. But the left hand side is a function call, meaning take `x` and convert it to an `int`, and you can't assign something (a list in this case) to a function call.

What you really want to do is change the right hand side of your looping expression. Instead of going through the list *elements* you want to go through the list *indices*.

```
for x in range(1,len(lines)):
    print lines[x][1] - lines[x-1][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, just a join of the loop placed in a print statement for the \n to trigger

```
print '\n'.join(str(lines[x][1]-lines[x-1][2]) for x in xrange(1,len(lines)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also go crazy without using `range` for indices:

```
for (first, second) in zip(lines[:-1], lines[1:]):
    print second[1] - first[2]
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) or [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) (there are slight differences in Python2) create tuples from all iterables that they are given. From the docs:

> This function [**zip**] returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

Since the order of lists is guaranteed, this will yield the elements offset by the slices introduced.

Here the first iterable is all the lines without the last and the second iterable is all the lines excluding the first (0 index).

Comment: +1 for novel use of `zip`. I tend to use `zip` for reading in files by column instead of row. Could you please explain exactly what you mean by creating tuples in this specific case--- I understand the slice notation you are using as well as subtracting the second column entry from the first, but how does it know to grab the correct entries?

Comment: @white_rabbit: I updated my answer to explain a little more what `zip` does and put in the links for `zip` and `izip`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do :

```
for x in range(1,len(lines)):
    #do something
```

this will loop from `1` to `len(lines) - 1`

Comment: By starting the loop from 0, this would mean that one of those print statements above would be `print lines[0][1] - lines[-1][2]`, in this case we would want the looping to start from the first element with `range(1,len(lines))` so that the first print statement reads `print lines[1][1] - lines[0][2]`